# How to create site in share programmatically?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

This topic has been up quite some times in the community (forums, blog posts etc) and the conclusion is that this should be done making a REST Post call to share and the url `/service/modules/create-site`

The reason is that some surf specific stuff like the site dashboard are created from the share side.

However, I have been trying this approach from different angles all day, always ending up with a HTTP 200 in the response and no share site created. Quite frustrating.

I'm running this on Alfresco Enterprise 4.2.3.3 (I suspect my problems is due to a recent change)

To strip this down to something that is easy to reproduce, I'm following Martin Bergljungs blog post on the subject (http://www.ixxus.com/blog201203creating-alfresco-share-sites-javascript/), starting with using curl like this:

- create a text file with login credentials (login.txt) with the following content (change to appropriate values):
  `username=admin&password=admin`
- create a text file with the json to create a site (site_data.json)
  `{"visibility" : "PUBLIC","title" : "My Test Site","shortName" : "mytestsite",
  "description" : "My Test Site created from command line", "sitePreset" : "site-dashboard"}`
- Get the JSESSIONID by requesting a ticket:
  `curl -v -d @login.txt -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://localhost:8081/share/page/dologin`
- copy the resulting JSESSIONID value into the following curl call:
  `curl -v -d @site_data.json -H "Cookie:JSESSIONID=<insert your jsessionid>" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" http://localhost:8081/share/service/modules/create-site`

output from curl:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
> POST /share/service/modules/create-site HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8081
> Cookie:JSESSIONID=5963B948684F562A278909AF466D2306
> Content-Type:application/json
> Accept:application/json
> Content-Length: 196
> 
* upload completely sent off: 196 out of 196 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 13:57:02 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

The latter curl call results in a HTTP 200 as seen above, but a login to share reveals there have been no site created what so ever :(

BTW. I have disabled the CSRF Token Filter.

UPDATE: 
I have verified that the above approach works to create a site on Alfresco Enterprise 4.1.5
I have verified that it also fails on Alfresco Community 4.2.e
This is reported as a bug: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-11706

UPDATE: Since the question was not clear to a reader I have reformulated it now

UPDATE:

Following Dave Websters answer, I been trying again using the following steps, still with CSRF Token disabled:

Login:
`curl -v -d @login.txt -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://localhost:8081/share/page/dologin`

Response:

> POST /share/page/dologin HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
>   Host: localhost:8081
>   Accept: */*
>   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length: 29
>
> ```
> * upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
> < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> * Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
> < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
> < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=058A52486E4EB12F94D1F95302732616; Path=/share/; HttpOnly
> < Set-Cookie: alfLogin=1417618589; Expires=Wed, 10-Dec-2014 14:56:29 GMT; Path=/share
> < Set-Cookie: alfUsername3=admin; Expires=Wed, 10-Dec-2014 14:56:29 GMT; Path=/share
> < Location: http://localhost:8081/share
> < Content-Length: 0
> < Date: Wed, 03 Dec 2014 14:56:29 GMT
> ```

Took the cookie values and inserted into Daves code (with the csrf-stuff stripped out):

`curl 'http://localhost:8081/share/service/modules/create-site' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=058A52486E4EB12F94D1F95302732616; alfLogin=1417618589; alfUsername3=admin;' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8081' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8081/share/page/site/erik/dashboard' -H 'X-Requested-With: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary $'{"visibility":"PUBLIC","title":"erik'","shortName":"erik'","description":"This site is auto generated","sitePreset":"site-dashboard"}' --compressed`

Still no share site generated though, and still a HTTP 200 Response. No errors in the logs either. This is driving me nuts :(

New Update (It works!):

I have now found out that you will need to "touch" a share webscript after making the login call before calling create-site with a post. I do this by making a get request in between. This somehow needs to be done to initialize the share session.

Comment: I fail to see a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the curl command I use to generate sites programatically. I insert the JSESSIONID, LOGINCOOKIECONTENTS and CSRFTOKEN (twice) contents manually, but getting them programatically should work.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8081/share/service/modules/create-site' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID={JSESSIONID}; alfLogin={LOGINCOOKIECONTENTS}; alfUsername3=admin; Alfresco-CSRFToken={CSRFTOKEN};' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8081' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8081/share/page/site/auto-gen-0/dashboard' -H 'X-Requested-With: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Alfresco-CSRFToken: {CSRFTOKEN}' --data-binary $'{"visibility":"PUBLIC","title":"auto-gen'$I'","shortName":"auto-gen-'$I'","description":"This site is auto generated","sitePreset":"site-dashboard"}' --compressed
```

The expected response is:

```
{
   "success": true
}
```

Comment: Thats great, now I only need to translate that into some java code using the Spring Surf HttpClient (If you have that kind of code lying aroud, please feel free to share it also :) )

Comment: From where do you get the Alfresco-CSRFToken for your request?

Comment: It's in a cookie called: Alfresco-CSRFToken. If you've disabled the CSRF token filter (as per your question), you can remove the whole of that cookie ( Alfresco-CSRFToken={CSRFTOKEN};)from the post header.

Comment: One more thing to add, the CSRF token cookie value needs to be url-decoded before set.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. It's not quite as simple as that: When the CSRF token is in the cookie it's encoded, but in the header it's decoded...