# cross domain call using REST Alfresco

Tags: rest, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using the REST API to upload a file. http://fiddle.jshell.net/876fzzd5/5/ is the pastebin.

I am using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload form plugin to upload cross domain.

IE debug tools shows that the correct response is received from the server. However the success callback is always called even if the file upload fails. If I don't use a cross domain Ajax call then the correct callback methods (success/error) are called.

Could some one let me know what might be the issue?

Comment: @Will Harrison I dont think its a cors filter issue. I tried to enable cors filter  and had the same issue. CORS requests need jasonp response call back. May be thats why its not invoking the correct call back methods.

Comment: Sounds like the issue I had a while ago when trying to create a site programmatically. The response was an empty HTTP 200 without the expected json (and nothing happended). I had to "touch" the API with a get call after getting the authentication token to make it work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251706/how-to-create-site-in-share-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Is this a CORS filter problem? If so, my installation of alfresco had the CORS filter commented out in the web.xml file. All I had to do was uncomment the filter. Also here is a post that shows you how to put the CORS filter in if it is not already there:
http://www.slideshare.net/jottley/cors-enable-alfresco-for-cors