# why is it so complicated to configure CORS origin on Alfresco

Tags: tomcat, alfresco

First please apologize my english :)

What is my problem with Alfresco Community 5.0.d:
I tried to fetch data from Alfresco, but alfresco is on another computer so I try ma http request and I have always

> cross origin not allowed from localhost:4220

I think setting Alfresco to enable cross origin is so complicated, I tried all tutorial all stack overflow I found but I have always this error message

I tried with another member of my team these links:

- http://fr.slideshare.net/jottley/cors-enable-alfresco-for-cors
- https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/other-apis/alfresco-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-02202015-1129
- http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html
- [AngularJS / Alfresco / CORS filter issue: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981648/angularjs-alfresco-cors-filter-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-heade)
- https://github.com/LuisSala/Alfresco-CORS-AMP
- http://anshu-alfresco-one.blogspot.ch/2015/08/enable-cors-in-alfresco-and-how-to-use.html

and many others on my xml but no success!

I tried also do my proper cors filter ... to add to header `add access-control-allow-origin` but no chance, when RUN cors filter is executed (my console said me) but this don't add header !

I tried so many thing but without result !!

I tried to use my request with service/ instead of s/ but NOT WORKS !!!
I tried use only POST request but NOT WORKS!!!

I don't understand why when I want a TICKET with this url `/alfresco/service/api/login?u=&pw=` it works, I can get ticket anywhere how and where this request is set ? I want do samething why only this request is allowed from anywhere and other not works !

Another question, I use alfresco community how can I contact alfresco to resolve my problem, I will pay my phone call/support ! because I think there is nobody to help people it's very damage ! Even on their forum nobody never answer, and actually forum is closed actually

**ALFRESCO version 5.0.d
TOMCAT version 7**

please help me!

Comment: What app do you use to fetch data from alfresco? Or you use Share, but repo and share run on different computers?

Comment: from webapp xhr http request... (angular) when I disable cors security on chrome using a chrome plugin (this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) ... it work's but when normal ..NOT WORKS !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using alfresco 5 then download [enablecors-1.0.jar](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/org/alfresco/enablecors/1.0/enablecors-1.0.jar) and place it in $ALF_HOME/modules/platform folder.it will solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thus the problem is in web-browser. You can use proxy to deceive web browser. Unfortunately I can't help you with proxy in angular. For example alfresco-share has own http proxy that allow to use CORS. Best regards

Comment: first thank you to your response but  no this is not web-browser problem! this is normal behavior I need to allow cross origin  with wildcard char, all server have this setting even alfresco I just want to enable it but without success with my config !   I succeed with ovveriding one abstract class which require into all my webervice and I add res.setHeader() this works but this is not good way I need it into web.xml but my web.xml into WEB-INF is never call ! this is problem